# Javascript push to array advanced

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have simple pagination function that outputs array.

```
exports.pagination = function(currentPage, nrOfPages) {
    var delta = 1,
        range = [],
        rangeWithDots = [],
        l;

    range.push(1);  

    if (nrOfPages <= 1){
    return range;
    }

    for (let i = currentPage - delta; i <= currentPage + delta; i++) {
        if (i < nrOfPages && i > 1) {
            range.push(i);
        }
    }  
    range.push(nrOfPages);

    for (let i of range) {
        if (l) {
            if (i - l == 2) {
                rangeWithDots.push(l + 1);
            } else if (i - l !== 1) {
                rangeWithDots.push('...');
            }
        }
        rangeWithDots.push(i);
        l = i;
    }

    return rangeWithDots;
}
```

handlebars:

```
{{#each pagination}}
            <li class="paginator-item">
                <a href="{{this}}" class="paginator-itemLink">{{this}}</a>
            </li>
{{/each}}
```

output:

```
1 ... 7 8 9 ... 19
```

It works well. But what i want to do is to seperate "number" and "href"
so i can use

```
{{#each pagination}}
            <li class="paginator-item">
                <a href="{{this.href}}" class="paginator-itemLink">{{this.number}}</a>
            </li>
 {{/each}}
```

But dont know how can i do this but unable. Cant find the correct way.
`rangeWithDots.push(number:'...',href:'')`. Tried lot of things but cant find that one correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can push as an object which consist of multiple properties.

So from the array you can read by accessing the object and the corresponding property.

i hope this will solve the issue.

```js
var rangeWithDots = []

rangeWithDots.push({href: "/sample", number: 5})

console.log(rangeWithDots)

//you can access the number by
console.log("number", rangeWithDots[0].number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost right! You just need to wrap your parameter to push as an object using `{...}`:

```
rangeWithDots.push({ number: ..., href: '...' });
```